# Gapps Script in Google Sheet Is Not Scrolling No Matter What I Do

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having troubles make Gapps Script scroll the window.

Basically, I want to send the user to the first non blank row from the buttom. My sheet has around 24000 rows. The first non blank row from the bottom is on 23500 row.

I'm using this script but not matter how many time I flush, nothing happens.

I am correctly getting the address of the lastFilledRow... It's just the sheet which never scrolls.

My code is:

```
function go_to_last_row() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc.....')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('All Leads')
  var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows()
  Logger.log(lastRow)
  
  sheet.getRange('A'+lastRow).activate()
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  
  var lastFilledRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate().getA1Notation()
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  Utilities.sleep(3000)  
  
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(lastFilledRow)).setValue('hello')
 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  
  Logger.log(lastFilledRow)
  
  Logger.log('done')

}
```

Any ideas how to force the window to actually scroll? I even set the value "hello" correctly, but still, the cursor never goes to that cell....

Comment: Is this a container-bound script? In other words, in your spreadsheet, if you go to Tools > Script editor, does this script open?

Comment: Yes, it does open there. I am not a total newbie too scripts but on this one... I just gave up and asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive). For some reason, [`SpreadsheetApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) doesn't provide the same privileged context that [container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) scripts afford. This is actually documented by Google, but in a relatively cryptic way

> Functions that are run in the context of a spreadsheet can get a reference to the corresponding Spreadsheet object by calling this function.

As a result of your question, I now interpret that to mean that the other open methods (those that don't include "Active") will not give you that reference to the corresponding Spreadsheet.

This is an abridged version of your code. Works with `getActive()`, but not `openById()`.

```
function go_to_last_row() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('All Leads');
  var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
  sheet.getRange('A'+lastRow).activate();
}
```

Comment: Aaah... you are a life saver... I would never figure this out. Thanks!